# Metasploit ssh_enumusers stops instantly

Tags: ssh, metasploit

When I try to run the : http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/auxiliary/scanner/ssh/ssh_enumusers

using the given options besides proxies

I get the output:

```
msf auxiliary(ssh_enumusers) > run
[*] [2015.04.16-14:09:15] 10.15.0.7:8022 - SSH - Checking for false positives
[*] [2015.04.16-14:09:16] Scanned 1 of 1 hosts (100% complete)
[*] Auxiliary module execution completed
```

It stops instantly and definitely doesn't try any of the given usernames. How do I get this module to work? As running the command "check" in this module, returns:

```
[-] Error while running command check: undefined method `rhost' for #<Msf::Modules::Mod617578696c696172792f7363616e6e65722f7373682f7373685f656e756d7573657273::Metasploit3:0xefb463c>

Call stack:
/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3/lib/msf/ui/console/module_command_dispatcher.rb:135:in `cmd_check'
/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:427:in `run_command'
/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:389:in `block in run_single'
/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:383:in `each'
/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3/lib/rex/ui/text/dispatcher_shell.rb:383:in `run_single'
/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3/lib/rex/ui/text/shell.rb:200:in `run'
/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3/lib/metasploit/framework/command/console.rb:38:in `start'
/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3/lib/metasploit/framework/command/base.rb:82:in `start'
/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3/msfconsole:48:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It is working for me. I get the same response from `check` as you did. Is it possible your USER_FILE is empty? When I run this module with an empty user file, I get the same results as you. USER_FILE is required and `> run` should give an error if USER_FILE is not set, so when you type `show options` what does it show as the USER_FILE?

Comment: how is this off topic?  The help center says "Topics include but are not limited to: ... security tools."  Metasploit is nothing if not a security tool.  Other Metasploit topics are closed with such comments as "If you are just trying to learn metasploit then this question is off topic here."  Thus we are reduced to a forum for cutting and pasting security best practices. Looking further, I see the majority of questions about learning metasploit are closed or on hold while none about learning nmap are closed or on hold. hmmm...

Comment: I added a bug report for the check issue at https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/5264

Comment: PR to resolve this issue landed in the master tree now. Details are at https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/5274

Comment: // , @ThoriumBR why was this issue closed?